# How to avoid capturing groups in RegEx splitting result?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I'm trying to use *re* to match a pattern that starts with '\n', followed by a possible 'real(r8)', followed by zero or more white spaces and then followed by the word 'function', and then I want to split the string at where matches occur.  So for this string,

```
text = '''functional \n   function disdat \nkitkat function wakawak\nreal(r8) function noooooo \ndoit'''
```

I would like:

```
['functional ',
 ' disdat \nkitkat function wakawak',
 ' noooooo \ndoit']
```

However,

```
regex = re.compile(r'''\n(real\(r8\))?\s*\bfunction\b''')

regex.split(text)
```

returns

```
['functional ',
 None,
 ' disdat \nkitkat function wakawak',
 'real(r8)',
 ' noooooo \ndoit']
```

`split` returns the matches' groups too. How do I ask it not to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use non-capturing groups, like this

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\n(?:real\(r8\))?\s*\bfunction\b')
>>> regex.split(text)
['functional ', ' disdat \nkitkat function wakawak', ' noooooo \ndoit']
```

Note `?:` in `(?:real\(r8\))`. Quoting [Python documentation for `(?:..)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but **the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern**.